# Scala json validator a string that contain URI

Tags: json, scala

Im trying to implement validation by using this article  [ScalaJsonCombinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators)

Basically  i want to get the value if exist and if not return **null**

```
val nextPage: JsResult[JsValue] = (ch.\("paging").\("next")).validate[JsValue]

    val nextUrl: String = nextPage match {
      case s: JsSuccess[String] => s.get
      case e: JsError => null
    }
```

### I have tow issue`s

1. the first is a warning

   ```
    Warning:(99, 19) non-variable type argument String in type pattern play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
     case s: JsSuccess[String] => s.get
         ^
   ```
2. the second is an error  because  the  string   is a URI with special
   characters im getting a scheme error

   val nextPage: JsResult[JsValue] = (ch.("paging").("next")).validate[JsValue]

   ```
   val nextUrl: String = nextPage match {
     case s: JsSuccess[String] => s.toString
     case e: JsError => null
   }  
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 9:  JsSuccess(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/396697410351933/feed?limit=200&access_token=623501864400497%7CGumAg3k6Eu
   ```

**What will be to correct way to validate this element  without using serialization.??**

thanks,

miki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're validating incorrectly. calling `validate[JsValue]` on a `JsValue` is meaningless, because it will *always* result in `JsSuccess[JsValue]`. The other problem is you're then trying to pattern match a `JsSuccess[String]` from a `JsSuccess[JsValue]`, which you cannot do for many reasons. One, the type argument is erased at runtime as noted by the compiler warning. And two, a `JsSuccess[String]` can't be a `JsSuccess[JsValue]`, the types aren't related.

   What you really need is `validate[String]`.
2. Probably impossible to debug unless you provide the relevant JSON.

---

There's a more elegant way of doing this, though. Since you don't seem to care about the failures (you're discarding them for `null`), you can just use `asOpt`. Here is where I say that if there's a chance there is no `next`, then `nextUrl` should be `Option[String]` instead of `String`, and you should never ever ever use `null` in Scala.

```
val nextUrl: Option[String] = (ch \ "paging" \ "next").asOpt[String]
```

If you for some reason must use `null`:

```
val nextUrl: String = (ch \ "paging" \ "next").asOpt[String].getOrElse(null)
```